# Why component doesn't render when I change the route?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-router

I have a template, and there is a component:

```
        <super-visor
            v-if="!top10ModeActivated"
            v-for="cart in getCarts(index + 1)"
            :cart="cart"
            :key="cart.position"
        ></super-visor>
```

As you can see, this component renders when `top10ModeActivated` is only `false`;

```
   computed: {
        top10ModeActivated() {
            return this.$store.state.moduleSearch.top10ModeActivated;
        },
   }
```

I put `debugger` to `top10ModeActivated` and it works only when component renders only for the first time. So I see my component, only when I refresh the page but not when I change the route.

Can anybody help me and describe me how I can fix this? Because I'm new to VueJS.

Answer (score 1):

Use methods because [computed properties are cached](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods). See below:

```js
   methods: {
        top10ModeActivated() {
            return this.$store.state.moduleSearch.top10ModeActivated;
        },
   }
```

and

```html
        <super-visor
            v-if="!top10ModeActivated()"
            v-for="cart in getCarts(index + 1)"
            :cart="cart"
            :key="cart.position"
        ></super-visor>
```

Comment: I made your suggestion but I have the same problem.

Comment: I deleted condition and I see this template only when reload the page.

Comment: A property is possible ".top 10 Mode Activated" is not reactive. Did you initialize it? =>
...
state: {
  moduleSearch: {
    top10ModeActivated: '...'
  },
  ...
}
...

Comment: but it doesn't work even when I deleted condition with this prop. It seems like component never renders when I change the route. Only when I reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing store state directly from computed property doesn't make it reactive. Use getters instead.
Create a Vuex getter which would return top10ModeActivated and then call that getter in a computed property to have it reactive.